# How to achieve a block of Z^(-0.5) in Simulink?

Tags: simulation, matlab

I'm doing simulation in Simulink of Matlab, but don't know how to get a Z^(-0.5) cell like this:[image]

Answer (score 1):

while @Andy aka captured the wider intent a practical implementation w.r.t. Simulink requires a re-evaluation of your sample time.

Remember in practice you can't have 1/2 a delay you can only have a different strobe.

A simulink solution would require the discrete sampling time twice what you require so a \$Z^{-1}\$ block would behave like a 1/2 sample. Make use of specific sampling time on a per block or subsystem/enable basis

Comment: IIRC, every symmetric filter with an even number of points yields a half sample delay

Answer (score 0):

The previous sample is created from the latest sample by Z^(-1) so Z^-(0.5) is the average of previous and latest. It's akin to creating a half sample in between latest and previous.

Comment: Z^(-0.5)≈ 0.5(1+1/z) is that what you mean?

Comment: It looks about right.